# Is there a shortcut to get to the /Resources/ folder in iPhone development?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, filesystems, cs193p

Is there a shortcut method much like NSHomeDirectory() and NSTemporaryDirectory to get to the resources folder within your project?

Is the /resources/ folder the best place to be storing a file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't store writable data in your Resources path, since it's inside the app bundle (which is signed). But it's a good place to store readonly data. As Codezy mentions, `[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]` is the path to it, but generally the better way to access files in it is `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:ofType:]` and its siblings (`...:inDirectory:`, etc.) The latter automatically handles localization when appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I store an SQL lite db in the resources folder.  Here is a sample of how I get the path.

```
NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]        
                                       stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ratings.sqlite"];
```

I store things in the resources folder if I want each new version to overwrite it, else I store it in the documents folder.

Comment: but this is only a read-only resource yes? you can't write to it there right? (2 backwards questions)